# Compiling and running code in runtime

Tags: vb.net, reflection

I am trying to compile and run code at runtime. I am using the  below code to achieve this. However, when i trying to invoke the method, simply a "Find Source" file browser dialog opens and the code is not run. Can anyone please help me here.

```
Dim VBP As New VBCodeProvider
Dim CVB As System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler

CVB = VBP.CreateCompiler
Dim PM As New System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters

PM.GenerateInMemory = True
PM.GenerateExecutable = True
PM.OutputAssembly = "RunCode.dll"
PM.MainClass = "MainClass"
PM.IncludeDebugInformation = True

Dim ASM As System.Reflection.Assembly
For Each ASM In AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies
    PM.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(ASM.Location)
Next
Dim CompileResults As System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults

CompileResults = CVB.CompileAssemblyFromSource(PM, sCode)

Dim CompileErrors As System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerError

For Each CompileErrors In CompileResults.Errors
    RTMainScript.AppendText(vbCrLf & CompileErrors.ErrorNumber & ": " & CompileErrors.ErrorText & ", " & CompileErrors.Line)
Next

Dim objRun As New Object
Dim vArgs() As Object

objRun = CompileResults.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("RunCode.MainClass", False, BindingFlags.CreateInstance, Nothing, vArgs, Nothing, Nothing)
If Not objRun Is Nothing Then
    Dim oMethodInfo As MethodInfo = objRun.GetType().GetMethod("Main")
    Dim oRetObj As Object = oMethodInfo.Invoke(objRun, BindingFlags.Static Or BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.NonPublic, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing) 'Find source dialog appears here
Else
    MsgBox("Compile Error")
End If
```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this error using your code. Perhaps there is a permissions issue writing the temp DLL file that it's generating.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is incomplete. You are using this method to compile the code:

```
CompileResults = CVB.CompileAssemblyFromSource(PM, sCode)
```

But you actually never specified what `sCode` is. If you are getting an open file browser dialog, then I am quite sure that your `sCode` is the cause of it. It must have been set somewhere while calculating the variable value to open a file.

If you are trying to change a piece of code that was used to compile from a file then changing the method from `CompileAssemblyFromFile()` to `CompileAssemblyFromSource()` is not enough. You need to dig more into the code and change all related methods.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your threading model is STA.

OpenFileDialog and similar objects will not operate correctly if the threading model is set to MTA.
If you must use MTA for some other reason then you can create your own custom OpenFileDialog class; sort of sucks.